# Vertical menu css3

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I am stuck on the creation of a vertical menu with submenu:

```
<ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Pages
        <ul>
            <li>Subpage</li>
            <li>Subpage 2</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Contact</li>
</ul>
```

Clicking on "Pages" the menu should be something similar to this:

[image]

Comment: what is your need ? css or javascript ?

Comment: I think you should google it : this is an example http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/nested_side_bar_menu/

Comment: Just google it, plenty of CSS vertical menu's. Looking for something like this? http://www.devinrolsen.com/pure-css-vertical-menu/

Comment: no, it isn't tha the problem, you should focus on the bars that surround the left part of the menu, i am unable to create the css to make it work like in the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic mechanic can be achieved like this:

```
ul li ul {
  display: none;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

li:hover ul {
  display: block;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/elias94xx/sCXus/

---

Without the use of images it's somewhat tricky to achieve the effect in your images above, but I got a decent example working:

[image: css menu tree]

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/elias94xx/sCXus/5/

Comment: thank you very much, the problem isn't that, but as you can see in the image linked in the post there are some bars that surround the left part of the menu, and i don't know a proper method to do it best

Comment: @Benjamin Do you need it in pure CSS ?

Comment: it is not important but if you can do it, it would be fantastic.

Comment: @Benjamin I edited my answer, this should give you an idea, how to work it out.

Comment: If you have any idea also on how to remove the ending part... don't forget to post it ;) thank you very much again.

Comment: @Benjamin It's tricky, but here you go:  http://jsfiddle.net/elias94xx/sCXus/4/ **Edit**: Even more improved: http://jsfiddle.net/elias94xx/sCXus/5/

Comment: Ok fantastic, this question is definitely resolved. Could i suggest you to post this also on Codepen.io ? Thank you very much.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sCXus/11/ i have a question, as you can see it doesn't work properly, why it has a white space when you hover on Pages (the sub-menu opens and the bar surrounding it don't arrive to the next item) Ideas to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

Try This

1. use this CSS:

   ```
   ul{
       list-style:none;
   }
   ul li ul{
       list-style:none;
       display:none;
   }
   ```
2. apply jQuery library and this function:

   ```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("ul li").click(function(){
           $(this).children('ul').show();
       });
   });
   ```